# Menu Toggle function not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

This works fine at all times except for the first time tab_toggle(0) is called.
when the first time this function is called the #box_home has `display:block;` so the function shouldn't do anything but whats happening is `#box_port`(the next div) is getting display:block; and `#box_home` remaining `display:block` as before. why is this happening. is it because when the function is called the variable has value undefined so doing some random thing.
Please answer this in javascript only, dont answer in jquery.
i couldnt make it work just this part in jsfiddle so i am sharing the entire webpage code 
http://goo.gl/dhTUDH

```
<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
function tab_toggle(x) {
    console.log("tab_toggle");
    var home    = document.getElementById("box_home").style;
    var port    = document.getElementById("box_port").style;
    var about   = document.getElementById("box_about").style;
    var contact = document.getElementById("box_contact").style;
    var box     = [home,port,about,contact];

switch (x) {
    case 0:
        if (home.display == "block") {
            console.log('end');
        } else if (port.display == "block") {
            box[0].display = "block";
            box[1].display = "none";
        } else if (about.display == "block") {
            box[1].display = "block";
            box[2].display = "none";
        } else {
            box[2].display = "block";
            box[3].display = "none";
        }
        break;
    default: 
        if (home.display == "block") {
            box[0].display = "none";
            box[1].display = "block";
        } else if (port.display == "block") {
            box[1].display = "none";
            box[2].display = "block";
        } else if (about.display == "block") {
            box[2].display = "none";
            box[3].display = "block";
        } else {}
        break;
    }
}
```

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a href="javascript:tab_toggle(0)">&#9664;</a>
<a href="javascript:tab_toggle(1)">&#9654;</a>
<div id="box_home"></div>
<div id="box_port"></div>
<div id="box_about"></div>
<div id="box_contact"></div>
```

---

```
<!-- CSS -->
#box_home{display:block;}\
#box_port{display:none;}
#box_about{display:none;}
#box_contact{display:none;}
```

Comment: provide us your code on fiddle and are you looking for jQuery solution

Comment: @RakeshKumar i know how to do it in jquery 
i want it in javascript.

Comment: If the “start value” (as coming from stylesheet or just being the default `block`) for display for the given elements is always the same, then you _can_ makes this work by reversing the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a style directly as a property, as in

```
home.display
```

Instead, use the `getComputedStyle()` method

```
getComputedStyle(home).display
```

Comment: i just thought using variables would decrease my code you are increasing it by adding methods on variables

Comment: Well would you rather have _increased_ code, or _not working_ code …?

Answer (score 0):

element.style will get the element's inline style. Try [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) or add a class.

```
getComputedStyle(box[0]).getPropertyValue("display")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what would you achieve, but this should work:

```
 var currentElement = 0;

(tab_toggle = function (x) {
  var home = document.getElementById("box_home").style;
  var port = document.getElementById("box_port").style;
  var about = document.getElementById("box_about").style;
  var contact = document.getElementById("box_contact").style;
  var box = [home, port, about, contact];
  if (currentElement + x < 0 || currentElement + x > box.length - 1)
    return;

  currentElement += x;
  console.log("toggled " + currentElement);

  for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].display = "none";
  }

  box[currentElement].display = "block";

})(0);
```